# twitter bootstrap modal hide show effects

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jquery-effects

I've got elements in a twitter bootstrap modal that I want to hide and replace with others.

The hide and show work, but trying to add an effect - slide for example - doesn't.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using bootstrap effects rather than trying to mix jquery and bootstrap stuff up.

I used a carousel in the modal, which was different to what I'd planned but worked just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the transition script?

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your modal html you can add a fade in class in order to let it slide in

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="testModal">
...
</div>
```